# Function not called for first click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

On checking a checkbox, I need to call a function. The first time I check the checkbox the function is not called whereas if I check it again, the function is successfully called. Please help me solve this issue. Here I have showed the part of my HTML and the function.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" onchange="LoadContactDetails()">
```

```
function LoadContactDetails() {
    $("#checkThen").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // ..........
         }
        else {
            // ..........
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why r u using both javascript & jquery in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach inline event handler use ,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" onchange="LoadContactDetails(this)" />

function LoadContactDetails(element) {
    alert(element.checked);
}
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4g7H3/)</kbd>

### OR

If you want to use jQuery event handler use,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" />

$(function() {
    $("#checkThen").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // checked
         }
        else {
            // unchecked
        }
    });
});
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev79n/)</kbd>

Comment: @user3363329 glad to help you my friend..please mark it as correct if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

You just bind the `change` event first time you clicked.

Remove the `onchange` attribute, then just bind the change event at the dom ready callback.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen">
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#checkThen").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            ..........
         }
        else {
            ..........
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkThen").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                ..........
             }
            else {
                ..........
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes exactly because 
u can use or fire onchange & click event both simulatneously

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onchange attribute in function LoadContactDetails().

**html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" onchange="LoadContactDetails()">
```

**js:**

```
function LoadContactDetails() {    
    if ($('#checkThen').is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
     }
    else {
         alert('Not-checked');
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/efEdB/)

```
                                      **Or**
```

You just bind the change event first time you clicked.

Remove the onchange attribute, then just bind the change event at the dom ready callback.

**Html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen">
```

**.js:**

```
$(function() {
  $("#checkThen").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
     }
    else {
        alert('Not checked');
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/m669b/)

Hope it should helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you bind `change` event every time when function `LoadContactDetails()` call.
(It's not correct way)

You can just call your code directly inside your function.

```
function LoadContactDetails() {
    if ($('#checkThen').is(":checked")) {
       alert('checked');
    } else {
       alert('Not-checked');
   }
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waksK/)

Answer (score 0):

In the first click you are binding an event to the checkbox. And from 2nd click onwards the callback function gets fired, and a new event binding will also happen. You can make it work by simply changing the code as follows,

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" >
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkThen").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // checked
         }
        else {
            // unchecked
        }
    });
});
```

Please follow this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) on getting an idea about callback functions

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Click" instead of "change. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

i tried all the solutions given here but it did not work for me  Finally, I found an easy way to solve this problem.I hope this will helpful for you also.

```js
function LoadContactDetails() {
    $("#checkThen").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          alert('hello')
         }
        else {
            alert('something wronge')
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkThen" onMouseDown="LoadContactDetails()"/>
```